# Firing keyboard events in Actionscript 2.0

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I use this to fire keyboard events in AS3:

```
dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,true,false,_charcode,_keycode));
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to achieve the same thing in AS2, is it even possible? I have to fire a key event to an external swf and I don't have the source of the swf.

Comment: I'm not sure it would work for keyboard events, and I haven't done AS2 for ages, but if I remember it right, you would use the AS2 version of mx.events.EventDispatcher to do dispatchEvent in AS2 code.

Answer (score 0):

There is no native event dispatching system in AS1/2. AS1/2 uses callbacks or handlers. You can write your own dispatching system using `EventDispatcher` class http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00002329.html But you need fire events by your own code.

1 way: click on btn and in Actions window write handler:

```
on (press) {
    // do smth or dispatchEvent
}
```

2 way: create button, select them, set instance name in Properties panel (for ex. `btnName`), select in timeline frame with your button and in Actions window write:

```
btnName.onPress = function () {
    // do smth or dispatchEvent
}
```

Answer (score 0):

dispatching events in AS2 is somewhat different than AS3, as most of the classes in AS3 already extend the EventDispatcher Class, however, in AS2, this is not the case.

In regards to AS2, some people choose to create an event dispatcher object within the classes the create, if they cannot directly extend the EventDispatcher Class:

```
public class Magic extends MovieClip{
    public var _dispatcher:EventDispatcher;

....
....
```

For any event, that event eventually translates to a String, so if you have the right characters, you can dispatch any event, without using the constant representation:

```
...
...
...
_dispatcher.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent(KeyboardEvent.UP));
// is the same as the following:
_dispatcher.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent("keyUp"));
```

So, what you are looking to do may be possible, but it HEAVILY depends on how the original coder modeled their code. To determine the structure of the code, you can decompile the swf using your favourite decompiler, and track down where the "listening" is happening.  Then you can attempt to target the "dispatching" object, and mimic a dispatch, as you require.

1. decompile the swf, and find out the object doing the dispatching, and the one doing the listening.
2. (I am guessing you are loading this external swf). Load the swf, and target the movieclip/object doing the dispatching:

   var _dispObject = _loadedSwf.mc.mc.mc.dispatchingObject;
3. do the dispatch as you require.

   _dispObject.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent("keyUp"));